# how to set IOS deployment target version to a point IOS release

Tags: ios, deployment, project, target, setting

I want to set the IOS deployment target as 5.0.1 so that my app doesnt run on devices running 5.0 or lower. However in xcode I only see options to either chose 5.0 or 5.1. I dont see options to select 5.0.1 or does it allow me to manually enter the value.

If I were to update the project file manually using a text editor, will it work as expected i.e users on 5.0 or below dont get an update in the appstore app on their device until they upgrade to 5.0.1 or later?

Comment: Curious - why support 5.0.1 but not 5.0? Is there some bug in 5.0 that's fixed in 5.0.1? I'd suggest supporting 5.1 and later. Any device that can run 5.0 can be updated to a newer version.

Comment: @rmaddy - 5.0.1 had an important bug fix that enabled a developer fix relating to the purging of the Cache folder.